# Symbolicate crash log - XCode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I am trying to symbolicate the crashed log & tried variuos methods.

1) symbolicating crash log from xcode(7.0.1) > Devices > All Logs > Re-Symbolicate logs

Nothing happens

---

Installed command line tools, `xcode-select --install`

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

2)from command line, `symbolicate “Crash.crash” "MyApp.app"`

Got error, `symbolicate: command not found`

---

3)`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash ~/Desktop/Crash/Crash.crash ~/Desktop/Crash/MyApp.app.dSYM`

Couldnt find any `DTDeviceKitBase.framework`

---

4) `atos -arch armv7 -o ~/Desktop/Crash/MyApp.app/MyAppName 0x00000001001de44c 0x1000d0000 + 1107020`

Got log, but not showing excat issue.

---

Just to verify my step 4 result is correct or not, I treid making crash by simply writing below code

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSLog(@"Here - %@", [arr objectAtIndex:5]);
```

But, after symbolicating crash log using step 4, Its shows `[classname functionName]` of some different class only. This makes me think that the symbolicated log of step 4 is not correct.

Edit 1: Adding crash log

```
Incident Identifier: 6D576A5F-78D7-4A34-AAE5-3B8609ADAD7B
CrashReporter Key:   fe1ade9551d87ac16f28d2305f8b4a4aabbdc406
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             MyApp [8388]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C02A9603-CB14-467C-B97B-1E5C18615DB2/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.MyAppapp.MyAppIdentifier
Version:             1.1.2 (1.1.2)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-11-17 10:30:21.105 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-11-17 10:30:11.610 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2253fd62 0x22438000 + 1080674
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x2fd9ec72 0x2fd98000 + 27762
2   CoreFoundation                  0x22454202 0x22438000 + 115202
3   MyApp                           0x000fcee4 0x17000 + 941796
4   UIKit                           0x259e4700 0x259d5000 + 63232
5   UIKit                           0x25a8e5a0 0x259d5000 + 759200
6   UIKit                           0x25a8e4c8 0x259d5000 + 758984
7   UIKit                           0x25a8da4c 0x259d5000 + 756300
8   UIKit                           0x25a8d786 0x259d5000 + 755590
9   UIKit                           0x25a8d4ec 0x259d5000 + 754924
10  UIKit                           0x25a8d484 0x259d5000 + 754820
11  UIKit                           0x259e1c1a 0x259d5000 + 52250
12  QuartzCore                      0x2540cf60 0x25400000 + 53088
13  QuartzCore                      0x2540894c 0x25400000 + 35148
14  QuartzCore                      0x254087d4 0x25400000 + 34772
15  QuartzCore                      0x254081c2 0x25400000 + 33218
16  QuartzCore                      0x25407fcc 0x25400000 + 32716
17  UIKit                           0x259da064 0x259d5000 + 20580
18  CoreFoundation                  0x22506620 0x22438000 + 845344
19  CoreFoundation                  0x22503d04 0x22438000 + 834820
20  CoreFoundation                  0x22504106 0x22438000 + 835846
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2245197c 0x22438000 + 104828
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2245178e 0x22438000 + 104334
23  GraphicsServices                0x2982a04c 0x29821000 + 36940
24  UIKit                           0x25a4397c 0x259d5000 + 452988
25  MyApp                           0x001dd5e8 0x17000 + 1861096
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x3033aaaa 0x30339000 + 6826


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x303ffdfc 0x303eb000 + 85500
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047fd0e 0x3047c000 + 15630
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3039f934 0x30356000 + 301364
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x2f5abbb8 0x2f5ab000 + 3000
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x2f5c566a 0x2f5ab000 + 108138
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x2fd9ef0e 0x2fd98000 + 28430
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x2f5c2dec 0x2f5ab000 + 97772
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x2f5c28b4 0x2f5ab000 + 96436
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x2fd9edba 0x2fd98000 + 28090
9   CoreFoundation                  0x22451a18 0x22438000 + 104984
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2245178e 0x22438000 + 104334
11  GraphicsServices                0x2982a04c 0x29821000 + 36940
12  UIKit                           0x25a4397c 0x259d5000 + 452988
13  MyApp                           0x001dd5e8 0x17000 + 1861096
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3033aaac 0x30339000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x303ec2c8 0x303eb000 + 4808
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3030ee44 0x302fd000 + 73284
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3030eb76 0x302fd000 + 72566

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x304009cc 0x303eb000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ce9c 0x3047c000 + 3740
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb74 0x3047c000 + 2932

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLConnection
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x303ffb38 0x303eb000 + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047e3dc 0x3047c000 + 9180
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047f2ac 0x3047c000 + 12972
3   Foundation                      0x2323aaa6 0x23181000 + 760486
4   CFNetwork                       0x22098ffa 0x21f8a000 + 1110010
5   CFNetwork                       0x220990ec 0x21f8a000 + 1110252
6   CFNetwork                       0x22086ebe 0x21f8a000 + 1035966
7   CFNetwork                       0x2204c7bc 0x21f8a000 + 796604
8   CFNetwork                       0x2204a8c2 0x21f8a000 + 788674
9   CFNetwork                       0x2208d1f4 0x21f8a000 + 1061364
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x302ff420 0x302fd000 + 9248
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x303095d4 0x302fd000 + 50644
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x303090a4 0x302fd000 + 49316
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3030b0d0 0x302fd000 + 57552
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3030c1f6 0x302fd000 + 61942
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ce22 0x3047c000 + 3618
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb74 0x3047c000 + 2932

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x304009cc 0x303eb000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ce9c 0x3047c000 + 3740
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb74 0x3047c000 + 2932

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x304009cc 0x303eb000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ce9c 0x3047c000 + 3740
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb74 0x3047c000 + 2932

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x304009cc 0x303eb000 + 88524
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ce9c 0x3047c000 + 3740
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb74 0x3047c000 + 2932

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLConnection
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x303ffb38 0x303eb000 + 84792
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047e3dc 0x3047c000 + 9180
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047f2ac 0x3047c000 + 12972
3   Foundation                      0x2323aaa6 0x23181000 + 760486
4   CFNetwork                       0x22098ffa 0x21f8a000 + 1110010
5   CFNetwork                       0x220990ec 0x21f8a000 + 1110252
6   CFNetwork                       0x22086ebe 0x21f8a000 + 1035966
7   CFNetwork                       0x2204c7bc 0x21f8a000 + 796604
8   CFNetwork                       0x2204a8c2 0x21f8a000 + 788674
9   CFNetwork                       0x2208d1f4 0x21f8a000 + 1061364
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x302ff420 0x302fd000 + 9248
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x303095d4 0x302fd000 + 50644
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x303090a4 0x302fd000 + 49316
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3030b0d0 0x302fd000 + 57552
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3030c1f6 0x302fd000 + 61942
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ce22 0x3047c000 + 3618
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb74 0x3047c000 + 2932

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x303ec518 0x303eb000 + 5400
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x303ec30c 0x303eb000 + 4876
2   CoreFoundation                  0x22505ba6 0x22438000 + 842662
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2250416c 0x22438000 + 835948
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2245197c 0x22438000 + 104828
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2245178e 0x22438000 + 104334
6   CFNetwork                       0x220069da 0x21f8a000 + 510426
7   Foundation                      0x23251996 0x23181000 + 854422
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ee64 0x3047c000 + 11876
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047edd6 0x3047c000 + 11734
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb80 0x3047c000 + 2944

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3040008c 0x303eb000 + 86156
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2250a32e 0x22438000 + 860974
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047ee64 0x3047c000 + 11876
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047edd6 0x3047c000 + 11734
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3047cb80 0x3047c000 + 2944

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x32b0e9dc      r6: 0x32afa840      r7: 0x01192418
    r8: 0x15716080    r9: 0x7420666f     r10: 0x32af9074     r11: 0x157160a4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x0119240c      lr: 0x3047fd13      pc: 0x303ffdfc
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Any helps.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information.  It's not important how you got them but just show the exception text, stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I have added crash log in question.

Comment: That stacktrace is not symbolicated and has no value.

Comment: Can you please expalin in more detail. I didnt understand that

Comment: The stacktrace is not symbolicated.  Those numbers should be the names of the class and method.

Comment: ok. Thats what I am trying to do using above mentioned steps.